# Can't print out lines of my csv file

Tags: python, csv, scraper

I am a novice coder working on a data scraping project. I was able to get my code to scrape the data working properly and I put it into a csv file that is organized as `[Name,Price,Shipping,Date]`. Now I want to take this data and put it into a list and change the variable types accordingly. something like `list = ["name", price(int),shipping(int), date (str)]` so I can feed this list into a constructor to make objects of each listing that I scraped.

Firstly, I just wanted some clarity. Is the csv file saving each piece of info as a string? I'm not sure on this.

The problem I am running into is everytime I try and print out a line of my csv file I keep getting an error. I want to print out the lines, clean up the data a bit then save them into a list. here is my code:

```
import csv

with open('Charmander.csv', newline = '') as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
    for line in data:
        print(line[0])
```

and I keep getting this back

```
Name
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Data mon\csv_to_list.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(line[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not very familiar with csv files and im not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone can teach me and give some insight that would be great, I just want to get some more progress on my project as soon as I can.

Comment: there are probably empty lines in your file. inspect it visually and check the `len(line)` before accessing an index.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that as i posted it, there is a null list between each line for some reason. I used try except and i got it to work

Comment: As you are a novice I would recommend you to look at `pandas` to handle tables in python. This has nothing to do with your question or answer though.

Comment: Thanks, will do! i decided to leave this up and not delete it when i realized the problem hoping someone would give me advice

Comment: Add `if len(line):` before your print statement.